# applying Nginx SSO with authorization to selected subdomains

Tags: nginx, single-sign-on

I need an open source SSO tool integrated with Nginx like authelia. It must be able to manage users' access to different sites. For example, the "s.com" domain is protected by SSO. This domain has four sub-domains named "a","b","c", and "d". Also, two users X and Y are the clients of these sites. After authentication, user X should only be able to access the sub-domains "a" and "b" , and user Y should only be able to access "c" and "d" sites. In other words X can not open "c.s.com" even if it is authenticated (it is not authorized to access "c.s.com"). Are there any tools that implement such a scenario with Nginx?